Отображение направленного графа ( networkx)
Всем привет!
Задачка у меня такая:
Есть направленный граф из двух вершин A, B, вершины связаны так:
A->B = 100
B->A = 50
При отрисовке у меня теряется информация о том, что путь из A->B занимает больше времени

Код программы:
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Создаем направленный граф
G = nx.DiGraph(directed=True)

# Добавляем вершины
G.add_node('A')
G.add_node('B')

# Добавляем ребра с весами
G.add_edge('A', 'B', weight=100)
G.add_edge('B', 'A', weight=50)

# Визуализация графа
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # Позиции вершин
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=500, node_color='lightblue', font_size=12)

# Отображаем веса ребер
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)

plt.title('Направленный граф с весами')
plt.show()

Как можно нарисовать дополнительное ребро с отдельным весом?

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=500, node_color='lightblue', font_size=12,connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1')

# Отображаем веса ребер
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels,label_pos=0.4,connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.1')



Да, спасибо, быстро нашел про connectionstyle, но как оказалось, поддержки этого аргумента нет на python3.8.
python3.10 + networkx==3.3 дает поддержку данного аргумента из коробки
